# how to do calculations in react with ternary operator as shown below?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to multiply the output with no. , but it directly gives no. only on screen .

this is what i wrote :

```
 <textarea className={` form-control text-${props.mode==='dark'?'light':'dark'} `} value={text} onChange={handleOnChange} id="myBox" rows={10} style={{backgroundColor: props.mode==='light'?'light':'dark'}}/>
                
<p className={` text-${props.mode==='dark'?'light':'dark'} my-1 `}>{0.008 * text.length>0?text.trim().split(" ").length:0} Minutes read </p>
```

it's giving 1 Minutes read instead of 0.008 Minutes read

Comment: what is `text` referring to here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround the number of words calculations in brackets `()`, to first calculate the number of words in the `text` then multiply with `0.008`.

```
<p className={`text-${props.mode === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'} my-1`}>{ 0.008 * ( text.length > 0 ? text.trim().split(" ").length : 0 )} Minutes read </p>
```